# ulimit file size 0

Tags: linux, unix

I accidentally typed `ulimit 0` instead of `ulimit -c 0`.  I've already tried `sudo ulimit unlimited` it gives me a file size error.  Is there a way to easily recover from this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely need to just do a non-graceful reboot to recover from that one. Hopefully you're using a journaled filesystem, in which case the chances of data corruption from not un-mounting properly will be fairly low.